# Pycharm printing an empty index that shouldn't be empty

Tags: python, yfinance

When running this code, I am expecting a table to print from data_period, however pycharm is returning an empty index when it is run. My friend, using the same code on pycharm, gets the desired table. So we think it has to do with the files that pycharm is using/storing information in. Any other ideas?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_market_calendars import get_calendar

# Get the calendar for the NYSE
nyse = get_calendar('NYSE')

# Get the trading days for the NYSE between the start and end date
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2023-01-26'
schedule = nyse.schedule(start_date, end_date)
trading_days = schedule.index

# Download the daily price action of the S&P 500
data = yf.download("SPY", start=start_date, end=end_date)

# Filter out days when the market is closed
data_period = data.loc[data.index.isin(trading_days)]


# Number of periods to calculate the standard deviation
averagingPeriod = 30
data_period['up'] = 100 * (data_period['High'].shift(1) - data_period['Open'].shift(1)) / data_period['Close'].shift(1)
data_period['down'] = 100 * np.abs(data_period['Open'].shift(1) - data_period['Low'].shift(1)) / data_period['Close'].shift(1)

# standard deviation
std_dev = data_period[['up','down']].rolling(window=averagingPeriod).std()
std_dev.rename(columns={'up':'up_std_dev','down':'down_std_dev'}, inplace=True)

# average
average = data_period[['up','down']].rolling(window=averagingPeriod).mean()
average.rename(columns={'up':'ave_up','down':'ave_down'}, inplace=True)

# H1 resistance level
data_period['H1'] = data_period['Open'] + (average['ave_up'] / 100) * data_period['Open']

# H2 resistance level
data_period['H2'] = data_period['Open'] + ((average['ave_up'] + std_dev['up_std_dev']) / 100) * data_period['Open']

# L1 support level
data_period['L1'] = data_period['Open'] - (average['ave_down'] / 100) * data_period['Open']

# L2 support level
data_period['L2'] = data_period['Open'] - ((average['ave_down'] + std_dev['down_std_dev']) / 100) * data_period['Open']

print(data_period)
```

I tried to get data_period to print out a full table, but I instead received an empty index.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What steps did you take to verify the results? For example, after `data = yf.download("SPY", start=start_date, end=end_date)` runs, what is the value of `data`? Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/; we do not provide a debugging service. We can answer questions about *why* code does what it does; but it is your responsibility before posting to identify **what** the problem is, in order to be able to **ask a specific question** about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.